# Compute $ A^2, A^3, A^4.$ Find a formula for $A^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let

$$A=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\ 
  0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1}
 $$
Compute $A^2,A^3,A^4$

Find a formula for $A^k $ for every $k > 0$. You do not need to prove that the formula is correct.

Comment: While many Readers will be able to follow the instructions *you* were given in this exercise, it is not clear why you did not attempt to take these basic steps yourself.

Answer (score 8):

Or, $A = I + N,$ where 
$$
N =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$
N^2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and $N^3 = N^4 = N^5 = \cdots = 0.$

As you can see in the other answers, the fact that $I$ and $N$ commute means we can expand this, and the fact that $N^3 = 0$ means the (binomial) expansion stops very soon.
$$ (I+N)^k = I + k N + \frac{k(k-1)}{2} N^2$$
because the binomial coefficient for $k$ elements taken $2$ at a time is $\frac{k(k-1)}{2} \; \; .$

$$ $$

The element in position $(1,3)$ becomes
$$ k + \frac{k^2 - k}{2} = \frac{k^2 + k}{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
A^k=
\begin{bmatrix}
1  &k & \frac{k(k+1)}{2} \\0  &1 & k \\ 0 & 0 &1 \\
\end{bmatrix} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Prove it by induction.

Answer (score 0):

$$A^2=\pmatrix{1&2&3\\ 
  0&1&2 \\ 0&0&1}
 \implies A^3=\pmatrix{1&3&6\\ 
  0&1&3 \\ 0&0&1}
 $$

$$A^4=\pmatrix{1&4&10\\ 
  0&1&4 \\ 0&0&1} \implies A^k=\pmatrix{1&k&S_k\\ 0&1&k \\ 0&0&1} $$

Where $S_k=S_{k-1}+k$

$S_k=S_{k-1}+k=S_{k-2}+(k-1)+k=S_{1}+....+(k-2)+(k-1)+k$
$S_k=1+....+(k-2)+(k-1)+k$
it gives $S_k=\frac {k(k+1)}2$

$$A^k=\pmatrix{1&k& \frac {k(k+1)}2\\ 0&1&k \\ 0&0&1} $$